# Gitea in Docker Swarm doesn't run in global mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-registry, gitea

I have a custom image of Gitea placed in a Docker Swarm, the implementation of the service is realized via Docker Compose. The issue is that, although I have specified that it has to run in global mode, it says global but I only have 1/1 replicas, that is wrong because I have two nodes in the swarm.
The strange thing is that other services run in global mode correctly with 2/2 replicas.
Can you tell me what is the problem?

This is the implementation on Docker compose:

```yaml
...
gitea:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/custom_gitea:92
    restart: always
    hostname: git.localdomain
    build: /data/gitea/custom
    # ports:
    #   - 4000:4000
    #   - 222:22
    environment:
      USER: git 
      USER_UID: 1000
      USER_GID: 1000
      GITEA__database__DB_TYPE: postgres
      GITEA__database__HOST: db:5432
      GITEA__database__NAME: gitea
      GITEA__database__USER: gitea
      GITEA__database__PASSWD: gitea
      GITEA__security__INSTALL_LOCK: "true"
      GITEA__security__SECRET_KEY: XQolFkmSxJWhxkZrkrGbPDbVrEwiZshnzPOY
    volumes:
      - /data/gitea:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /data/gitea/app.ini:/data/gitea/conf/app.ini
    deploy:
      mode: global
    depends_on:
      - db
      - openldap
      - openldap_admin
    networks:
      - vcc
...
```

These are my services:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by building and pushing from both nodes with the new images into the registry.
Now it works in global mode with 2/2 replicas.